# Send a message to all android clients of a certain pc application

Tags: java, android

I have an android app that connects to a computer version of the app. The computer version stores a list of people in the wait line. It is pretty much a wait line manager. New people come in the peopleInLine variable grows in one, people go out peopleInLine decreases in one.

My goal is to update all users of the app whenever peopleInLine changes.

Only the people who are connected to the computer version in the moment receive the updates.

I thought of:

Adding a peopleInLine field in a database and the computer version updates it when peopleInLine changes. The clients go and check the peopleInLine field every second to see if anything changed.

Or

Keep the connection between the clients and server(I'm using sockets) and whenever peopleInLine changes the server sends it through the socket.

The problem  is that the server will be in a computer that will be in a store managed by the store employees. I think the second solution can put a lot of pressure in the computer assuming millions of people are connected at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to maintain the sync between the clients and the server is using sockets. You can join all clients to a multicast address, and when the server changes state it sends the message to the multicast address and all your clients will receive it.

If you don't want to use sockets you can implement a REST API in the server and run a thread on the clients to periodically (lets say 10 seconds) check if the server changed. (This is a very naive solution)

Other solution would be to use another service to notify the apps that the server status changed. (e.g. Google Firebase)

Good luck

Comment: Ok...Thanks...so would it be a naïve solution to make the wait line manager end point the server? Assuming the wait line manager will be in a computer of a store and that computer used by their employees.

Comment: The multicast would in a higher level be sent directly from the computer store for each of the millions of users who will be using the app in their phones